# How to create report with time interval Salesforce

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, report-chart

I want a report Salesforce which shows the number of records created in a time interval like below:
[image]

Here the report displays the number is records created in October with the particular time interval.

Is it possible to achieve this using Salesforce report.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try find Tableau
Salesforce has renamed Tableau CRM "Salesforce CRM Analytics," and along the way added new features and dashboards. Coming later this year will be vertical-specific integrations, Slack apps and a search analytics tool.

Comment: Thank you @Victor Onyshko
I have extracted the time from created date and managed to do the report